# svn repository on Windows network share

Tags: svn, filesystems, berkeley-db, network-share, fsfs

Is it safe for multiple computers to concurrently access an svn repository stored on a shared filesystem?

I'm building an application in which each Windows client machine has a local working set of files, and can periodically synchronize with the rest of the team. From a server standpoint, I'd like to rely on nothing except a Windows shared mount point. Does the svn file:// URL protocol support shared filesystems, or does it assume that the filesystem is local?

The [Subversion docs](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#portability) mention issues with BDB and FSFS in Win9x environments, but it's not clear to me whether or not repositories concurrently accessed via file:// URLs are safe in more recent versions of Windows (or other operating systems, for that matter).

**Edit**
The application I'm building will be using svn directly, so I'm willing to build a relatively constrained environment if it'll permit a safe concurrent shared collaboration environment.

Comment: What is the problem you're actually trying to solve / the constraints you're having to work around?

Comment: Good question.

I'm building a Windows desktop app with collaboration features. The app needs to run in an environment in which the only guaranteed shared communication medium is a Windows (CIFS) mount.

Right now, I've got a solution that works, but I'd rather use an abstraction like SVN than deal with maintaining all the locking and file handling issues myself, for a number of reasons.

Basically, my persistence model is a list of transaction log records, which I replay when the app starts. So "all" I need is a way to collaboratively maintain an ordered list, and the inevitable conflicts.

Answer (score 11):

The Tortoise SVN docs actually strongly discourage it - see [this link](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share).
.

To summarise:

> file:// access is intended for local,
>   single-user access only, particularly
>   testing and debugging.

Comment: Those are the TortoiseSVN docs, not the svn docs themselves. I wonder whether that's a limitation / opinion of the TortoiseSVN guys, or a problem with svn itself.

Also, I'm willing to make a lot of concessions around environment restrictions; if I can find a narrow set of requirements that *do* work, I'll happily constrain myself to them (assuming that one of the requirements isn't "run a server process").

Comment: I somehow suspect that the Tortoise developers know a bit more about Subveersion than you or I do. Tortoise is built on the Subversion code, so I would guess it is a basic Subversion limitation.

Comment: They certainly know more than I do, but I wouldn't be surprised if their recommendations are for pretty general-purpose usage. I'm willing to make a lot of concessions to avoid writing my own distributed file sharing code, so am more interested in what is possible to do safely, rather than what is recommended.

Comment: Well, I think you are making a big mistake. Use of single-user software on Windows shares  by multiple users has always been fraught with problems. But it's your funeral.

Comment: Understood. It's not clear to me that svn + file:// is "single-user software", though. Some distributed filesystems do support locking, and with that, it's certainly possible to build a correct solution. I'm unsure if svn is one such solution, though.

Comment: From personal experience, I would NOT do this! Just setup a server. It's not hard and will save you many headaches.

Comment: Judge: what experiences are you referring to? In my environment, I cannot deploy a server, so that's not an option.

Comment: @Patrick: Then set up some server in a virtual machine and run that on some machine.

Comment: I think the phrase "set up a server" makes people run away screaming.  All we're actually talking about here is running svnserve or an apache module on some system somewhere.  You can put it on your own desktop if you want (not recommended; put it on the fileserver that you were considering using for file://).  SVN takes very few system resources, it doesn't need a dedicated system.

Comment: @meadow: You're probably right about the term "server". Let me add that it doesn't even require Apache. The `svn:` protocol is fine even without. (The advantage of a virtual machine is that it is easy to move it. That's handy when you don't have enough hardware resources to run a dedicated machine or when you're not allowed to change an existing one.)

Comment: @rmeador: I agree completely. However, like you said, "set up a server" sets off alarm bells, so the product that I'm developing is designed to run in a server-less environment, in which the only collaboration space is shared disk.

Comment: @sbi: to be clear, I'm considering using svn /in/ the product, not /to build/ the product. We're already happily using git (on http://unfuddle.com, which rocks) for SCM.

Our product has specific collaboration needs, and our sales process demands a "server-less" option for our clients, in which there is no separate server process required to enable these features. However, we can rely on an existing CIFS mount (over which we have no control, and our clients are unwilling to assert control). We're considering svn since it is a nice abstraction, and evolves nicely to server-full deployments.

Comment: @Patrick: I didn't understand that SVN was meant to be used _in_ the product. Sorry.

Answer (score 10):

Another question is similar, but was asked re: performance: 
[Subversion protocol performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372569/subversion-protocol-performance/372588#372588)

The SVN Book recommends that you *do not* use the file:// protocol for multiple users

[Choosing a Server Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html):

> Do not be seduced by the simple idea of having all of your users access a repository directly via file:// URLs. Even if the repository is readily available to everyone via a network share, this is a bad idea. It removes any layers of protection between the users and the repository: users can accidentally (or intentionally) corrupt the repository database, it becomes hard to take the repository offline for inspection or upgrade, and it can lead to a mess of file permission problems (see the section called “Supporting Multiple Repository Access Methods”). Note that this is also one of the reasons we warn against accessing repositories via svn+ssh://  URLs—from a security standpoint, it's effectively the same as local users accessing via file://, and it can entail all the same problems if the administrator isn't careful

Comment: Interesting... thanks for the link! I wonder what repository corruption issues they're concerned about.

Comment: IIRC, SVN uses files for locking, not actual filesystem-level locks (since they're not uniformly supported across filesystems and operating systems).  It's possible for a race condition to exist on a network share because the filesystem operations that are assumed to be atomic (i.e. move) are not guaranteed to be atomic when being accessed over a network.  This was explained to me in depth at one point by the SVN devs, but I may have forgotten some details, but I think that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 5):

From a technical point of view it is perfectly possible to use the file:// protocol with multiple users:

The corruption will **NOT** occur on standard svn usage, as subversion uses its own locking mechanisms on FSFS. Otherwise the SVN book would state clearly to avoid such a setup as it mentioned this issue in BDB backend.

However, the *real* problem is how to limit the access to the repository database to not access the repository data with any other arbitrary tool?

If you use file:// everybody can open each file inside your SVN repository and change its contents which will lead surely to repository corruption.

Heck, every user can delete the whole repository!

You cannot limit the access to svn tools and so you **should not** use file:// protocol.

Comment: UM, I think there's a difference between FSFS and the `file:` protocol, no?

Comment: Do you have any support for why corruption won't occur, or is that based on the (probably legit) assumption that the SVN guys would avoid file corruption in any environment?

Comment: As meadows stated: "It's possible for a race condition to exist on a network share because the filesystem operations that are assumed to be atomic (i.e. move) are not guaranteed to be atomic when being accessed over a network.", However I do not have any insight in this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head (and I was not able to find any information online), I would think that if you are using an SVN client that supports the file:// protocol ([TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), for example), it should work correctly.

However, and unfortunately I cannot find the document, I do remember there being certain problems with the file:// protocol and SVN.  If possible, I would suggest setting up an SVN server ([VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) works very nicely and is easy to setup) rather than relying on a Windows share.

**Edit:** I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598/any-disadvantages-in-accessing-subversion-repositories-through-file-for-a-solo) on Stackoverflow.  It seems as though there is not a problem using the file protocol.

**Edit 2:** Neil's link is what I had read awhile back and does discourage the file protocol.  However, if using the file:// protocol means the difference between using and not using source control, I would recommend at least using that.  Some source control is better than nothing.

Comment: I agree with using VisualSVN over a share.

Comment: I disagree strongly with your second edit - unreliable source control is worse than none at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're setting yourself up for problems with this approach.  Windows CIFS (the windows file sharing protocol) has a lot of known issues with oplocking and simultaneous modification, so it's either going to be dog slow, unsafe, or both.

A much, **much**, better solution is to set up a real SVN server instead of using file:// URLs.

Comment: I'm perfectly happy with "dog slow", as it turns out. Even "cat slow" would be ok. Just not "unsafe".

I understand that setting up a server is a better approach, but it's not an option for this product, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

That's right bro...

I've been there. I too used the file system to share the "svn server" between a couple of machines... The only thing I got was corrupted files and big headaches...

Instaled a svn server (CollabNetSubversion Server), and now everything is running smooth... Except for the times I screw it myself... but this is another story....

Cheers.

Aldo

Comment: What sorts of corruption issues did you run into? Were you using BDB or FSFS? What sort of filesystem were you using?

Answer (score 0):

The way we did it on Windows was to use Apache to serve up our files.  [Here](http://svn.spears.at/)
We are very happy with this setup.

Comment: Or you can have a tool do it for you: the VisualSVN server.