# Is it possible to create Tortoise SVN repository in local machine to collaborate with another person on different place?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I don't know if it is really possible.

I want to create a new repository in new drive (Suppose D:) where I will create a new project.
Now, I would like to checkout the project in another drive (Drive E) from where I will be working on project and commit. And also, I would like my friend to work on same project, so he can also commit from his home which should get saved to D: repository.

Is this possible ? I know we can use Git as an alternative to store codes safely online. But I would like to do it in my local machine and collaborate with my friend. For safety propose, I will make regular backup of main repository i.e drive D so codes won't get lost.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible. Setting up a local repo with tortoise is as easy as right clicking an empty directory and hitting "Create repository here". From there you "simply" have to share over network. [svn repository on Windows network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289850/svn-repository-on-windows-network-share) for example.